# Why do none of the sorcerers in Dr. Strange have a ranged attack?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, doctor-strange, doctor-strange-2016

They said they could conjure weapons, but all of them chose some sword or whips. No guns or arrows?

Comment: Could you expand on this please? Why do you think they should have guns or arrows?

Comment: @Mooz Like in the army they have spearmen and archers (they are an army against the dark dimension, right?). They look stuck in the medieval world (except the wifi joke). And some arrows would be practical. Otherwise, some mundane martial artists would be more effective (normal people know how to use gun and stuff).

Comment: This also begs the question of why magical *sorcerers* choose to do battle in such a traditionally *physical* sense. Surely magic is not so mundane?

Answer (score 7):

As to the *general* lack of ranged weapons being used in the film, this probably relates to the style of martial arts used (named [*Kamar-Taj*](http://marvelhorror.wikia.com/wiki/Kamar-Taj) after the temple) which largely seems to be based on melee-style weaponry.

Since Kaecilius' henchmen were all former acolytes of the Sorceror Supreme, it stands to reason that the protagonists and antagonists would all fight in much the same way, using much the same weapons.

---

That all being said, on several occasions we see Kaecilius (and his henchmen) creating spears which they then *throw* at Strange.

Comment: Which then begs the question "Why were all of the sorcerors using a martial arts style that emphasized hand-to-hand melee?" My best (out of universe) guess is that for dramatic purposes the directors didn't want two wizards blasting away at each other with fireballs from 50 yards apart.

Comment: @RobertF - Well, presumably a desire to avoid it looking too much like Harry Potter :-)